# why doesn't internet explorer 9, 10, 11 work with flex or rgba

Tags: html, css

This site is quite interesting, I want to use it in some design i am about to develop.  But lo and behold in internet explorer the transition on hover doesn't seem to work at all , it just jumps from state=nothing to state=everything, why is this the case ?

I have posted the css code below and a link to the codepen http://codepen.io/dp_lewis/pen/sDwlz

CSS

```
body {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  transition: flex 300ms ease-out, color 200ms ease-out;
  padding: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255,0);
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  background: #f2b635;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #f19a2a ;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  background: #49b3e8 ;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  background: #00a0e6;
}

li:nth-child(5) {
  background: #f25648;
}

li:hover {
   flex: 3;
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

Comment: I know that it has something to do with flex but there must be a workaround/addition to make it work for i.e ?

Answer (score 0):

in the end I did away with flex and just referred to standard rgba ... problem solved, kinda